# How To Subscribe To Websocket API Channel Using Python?

Tags: python, api, python-3.x, websocket

I'm trying to subscribe to the Bitfinex.com websocket API public channel `BTCUSD`.

Here's the code:

```
from websocket import create_connection
ws = create_connection("wss://api2.bitfinex.com:3000/ws")
ws.connect("wss://api2.bitfinex.com:3000/ws")
ws.send("LTCBTC")
while True:

    result = ws.recv()
    print ("Received '%s'" % result)
    
ws.close()
```

I believe `ws.send("BTCUSD")` is what subscribes to the public channel?  I get a message back I think is confirming the subscription `({"event":"info","version":1}`, but I don't get the stream of data afterward. What am I missing?

Comment: If you are working with an API, read the docs first. http://docs.bitfinex.com/#subscribe-to-channels

Comment: I have throughly read those documents.  And as far as I can tell, I'm missing the proper code to subscribe to the channel.  Yet going through all the documentation here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/websocket-client/ then send('LTCBTC') is the proper way to subscribe.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you are mixing here 2 different python packages. One is the [websockets](https://pypi.org/project/websockets/) package which is the line you eventually commented out (`#ws.connect("wss://api2.bitfinex.com:3000/ws")`), and the other one is the actual package you are using which is [websocket-client](https://pypi.org/project/websocket-client/)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[The documentation](http://docs.bitfinex.com/#message-encoding) says all the messages are JSON encoded.

> **Message encoding**
>
> Each message sent and received via the Bitfinex’s websocket channel is encoded in JSON format

You need to import `json` library, to encode and decode your messages.

[The documentation](http://docs.bitfinex.com/#public-channels) mentions three public channels: `book`, `trades` and `ticker`.
If you want to subscribe to a channel, you need to send a subscribe event.

Example of subscribing to the LTCBTC trades, according to [the documentation](http://docs.bitfinex.com/#trades70):

```
ws.send(json.dumps({
    "event":"subscribe",
    "channel":"trades",
    "channel":"LTCBTC"
})
```

Then you also need to parse the incoming JSON encoded messages.

```
result = ws.recv()
result = json.loads(result)
```

Comment: @Emily if an answer solved your issue, consider accepting it, it rewards the answerer and helps future visitors identify solutions easier

Comment: Did you figure out how to subscribe to multiple events concurrently?

Comment: do you need to define a function to process the data? can you update your answer with full code maybe?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to send parameters on open and add ssl to prevent errors

```
import websocket
import ssl
import json

SOCKET = 'wss://api-pub.bitfinex.com/ws/2'

params = {
    "event": "subscribe",
    "channel": "book",
    "pair": "BTCUSD",
    "prec": "P0"
    }

def on_open(ws):
    print('Opened Connection')
    ws.send(json.dumps(params))

def on_close(ws):
    print('Closed Connection')

def on_message(ws, message):
    print (message)

def on_error(ws, err):
  print("Got a an error: ", err)


ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(SOCKET, on_open = on_open, on_close = on_close, on_message = on_message,on_error=on_error)
ws.run_forever(sslopt={"cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE})
```

Comment: That's not the same WebSocket library used in OP's code.